# Why SparkContext creates a lot of connections to Hive Metastore and scans all databases?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

We've been informed by a team that manages and monitors our hadoop cluster that our Spark jobs (a few hundred of them) have a negative impact on a cluster. Apparently, every single job that creates SparkContext also automatically creates a lot of connections to a Hive Metastore and "scans" all databases and tables (see the logs below).

After doing some test we observed that right after we create a SparkContext using Spark 1.6 (*/usr/hdp/current/spark-client*) we observe the behaviour described above. Once we switch to Spark 2 (*/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client*) we don't see any connections to Hive Metastore.

Here's the code:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client"
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = " --conf spark.logConf=true --master yarn --driver-memory 25g --num-executors 50 --total-executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 25g pyspark-shell"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS
sc = SparkContext(appName="my_app_name")
```

We use: HDP 2.5; Spark 1.6 (PySpark API); Hive: 1.2.1; Cluster Manager: Yarn

Can you guys explain why this happens with Spark 1.6 and what is the possible solution (except switching to Spark 2) to avoid making all these connections to Hive Metastore? Any advice in which direction to dig is much appreciated.

I've looked at hadoop and hive config properties, but I've no idea if changing one or more of them will help us. I also read about HiveSupport(), but I believe it can only be used starting from version 2.0.

> 2019-09-10 10:32:26,662 INFO [pool-7-thread-56114]:
>   HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@
>   ip= cmd=get_all_databases 2019-09-10 10:32:26,898 INFO
>   [pool-7-thread-56114]: HiveMetaStore.audit
>   (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@ ip= cmd=get_functions:
>   db=db1 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,902 INFO [pool-7-thread-56114]:
>   HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@
>   ip= cmd=get_functions: db=db2 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,904 INFO
>   [pool-7-thread-56114]: HiveMetaStore.audit
>   (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@ ip= cmd=get_functions:
>   db=db3 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,905 INFO [pool-7-thread-56114]:
>   HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@
>   ip= cmd=get_functions: db=db4 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,907 INFO
>   [pool-7-thread-56114]: HiveMetaStore.audit
>   (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@ ip= cmd=get_functions:
>   db=db5 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,909 INFO [pool-7-thread-56114]:
>   HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@
>   ip= cmd=get_functions: db=db6 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,910 INFO
>   [pool-7-thread-56114]: HiveMetaStore.audit
>   (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@ ip= cmd=get_functions:
>   db=db7 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,912 INFO [pool-7-thread-56114]:
>   HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@
>   ip= cmd=get_functions: db=db8 pat=* 2019-09-10 10:32:26,914 INFO
>   [pool-7-thread-56114]: HiveMetaStore.audit
>   (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(319)) - ugi=@ ip= cmd=get_functions:
>   db=db9 pat=*
>
> ...

Comment: Are you stopping spark context every job run ?

Comment: _with out seeing how you are accessing your code it will be like shooting in the dark. so please post out line code which you are using and causing the problem to sharp shoot the issue._

Comment: @ Prateek, I'm not stopping the spark context.
@Ram Ghadiyaram, I've added the code that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: how are you accessing your dataframe/panda from python is what i am interested in

Comment: I'm not accessing any dataframe, I'm just creating SparkContext object and I get all these connections to Hive Metastore.